# Ubuntu server ftp no puedo subir ficheros por filezilla . TLS activado

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, ubuntu-server

tengo un dir en mi servidor para subidas ftp desde dicho protocolo:

```
/home/invitado/ftp

hola@mundo:/home/invitado/ftp# ls -la
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x 2 invitado invitado 4096 Apr  3 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 invitado invitado 4096 Apr  3 14:14 ..
```

Despues por filezilla le doy a `crear fichero` e intento crear un fichero: `holamundo.txt`.

Y el log me dice:

```
Estado: Comenzando la subida de Empty file
Comando:    PASV
Respuesta:  227 Entering Passive Mode (167,71,6,167,193,201).
Comando:    STOR holamundo.txt
Respuesta:  553 Could not create file.
Error:  Error crítico de transferencia de archivo
```

Tengo TLS activado. No se si es que tengo que meter el user invitado en el grupo `ftp` no lo se.

Comment: Buenas @josanangel, sospecho que es un tema de permisos del sistema de ficheros en el servidor. Puedes adjuntar log del servidor ftp? que servidor ftp utiltizas? El log que has puesto es del cliente, verdad? Saludos!

Comment: @gilito Buenas, ya consegui solucionarlo, era un  tema de configuracion, voy a poner una respuesta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para arreglarlo he tenido que hacer 2 cosas:

1. Dar permisos de escritura al usuario en el directorio `ftp`.
2. Editar el fichero `/etc/vsftpd.conf` y añadir esto: `allow_writeable_chroot=YES`.

Con eso ya me deja acceder sin problemas a el dir ftp